# How to find $a, b$ and $c$ from this system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $a$, $b$ and $c$ from:
$$
\begin{align}
a+c &= 3 \\
b+a &= 2  \\
c+b &= -1 \\
\end{align}
$$
I tried the following way, the answer comes wrong:
$$(a+c) + (b+a) = 3+2$$

Comment: Hint:  first equation tells us $c=3-a$.  Now substitute that into the third.

Comment: Hint: Add the first two equations (as you did), then subtract the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a+c)+(c+b)+(b+a)=3+2-1$$
$$2(a+b+c)=4$$
$$a+b+c=2$$
Then if $a+b+c=2$ and $a+c=3$ then $b=-1$

Then if $a+b+c=2$ and $a+b=2$ then $c=0$

Then if $a+b+c=2$ and $b+c=-1$ then $a=3$

Answer (score 1):

$$a+c=3.....(1)$$
$$b+a=2.....(2)$$
$$c+b=-1.....(3)$$

Try your way and solve like this-

$$(a+c)+(b+a)=3+2$$
$$2a+c+b=5.......(4)$$
Now, subtract equation(3) from (4)
$$ \begin{array}\ 2a+c+b=5 \\\;\;\;\;\;-c-b=1\\ \hline2a\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=6
 \end{array}$$
$$2a=6\;\implies a=3$$
Now, Put the value value of $a$ in equations(1) and (2)-
$$3+c=3\;\implies c=0$$
$$b+3=2\;\implies b=-1$$

I hope it'll help.